# Installing driver 32bit on win7 64bit

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, 32-bit, network-printer, multi-function-printer

I need to get to work network scanner, printing already works via drivers from canon site,
I installed scangear toll as well but when I add scanner from control panel it's not showing canon printer only some xerox and lexer listed, and scanning is not functioning

Comment: 32 bit software should work though

Comment: You cannot use a 32-bit diver on a 64-bit operating system.  If the 64-bit driver wasn't signed that coudl be solved.

Answer (score 1):

> **Installing driver 32bit on win7 64bit**

["Device drivers designed for 32-bit versions of Windows won't work on computers running a 64-bit version of Windows."](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows-vista/32-bit-and-64-bit-Windows-frequently-asked-questions)